# cant trigger javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 success: function (data) {
        if(data=='alreadysubmit')
                                 {
            alert("Sorry,but you have already submitted your answer");
                            $.getScript('static/js/draw.js', function()
                    {
                        alert("hi");
                    });
                                 }
        else{
            $("input:checked").next().text('Votes:'+data);
            }
     }
```

what above is a snippet of my code, which is supposed to load Google Visualization APT,in the javascrpit draw.js.  The draw.js is somewhere else in my local drive and I thought I can trigger it in the $.getScript function because in the draw.js there are some functions that I need to use for the current page. btw, the alert("hi") did take effect and the page kept loading... Am I supposed to do this? the idea is that I want to use draw.js only if the condition is met,if(data=='alreadysubmit'). Thank you in advance.

Comment: *The draw.js is somewhere else in my local drive*. How do you open the current page? Can you load the script by typing the URL directly in the address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple lines inside a conditional block must be surrounded by `{` and `}`.

So:

```
if (data=='alreadysubmit')
   alert("Sorry,but you have already submitted your answer");
   $.getScript('static/js/draw.js', function() {
       alert("hi");
   });
```

becomes:

```
if (data=='alreadysubmit') {
   alert("Sorry,but you have already submitted your answer");
   $.getScript('static/js/draw.js', function() {
       alert("hi");
   });
}
```

---

Your snippet fully corrected in this regard:

```
if (data == 'alreadysubmit') {
   alert("Sorry,but you have already submitted your answer");
   $.getScript('static/js/draw.js', function() {
       alert("hi");
   });
}
else {
   $("input:checked").next().text('Votes:'+data);
}
```

Comment: thats my bad, I coped the codes directly my Eclipse and thought I had the curly-bracket. I fixed it but the problem remained... Thank you for the headsup

Comment: @Clinteney: You haven't actually stated what the problem _is_.

Comment: is what i did above the way to trigger another static javascript file? I want to load the draw.js if the condition is met,if (data == 'alreadysubmit'), but what I got is a loading page... I have already done coding in draw.js and it supposed to draw a figure after this line $.getScript('static/js/draw.js')

Comment: @Cliteney: Look in your [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) console and check that the script file was found.

Answer (score 1):

```
 success: function (data) {
        if(data=='alreadysubmit'){
            alert("Sorry,but you have already submitted your answer");
                            $.getScript('static/js/draw.js', function()
                    {
                        alert("hi");
                    });
        }else{
            $("input:checked").next().text('Votes:'+data);


        }
     }
```

This?

Comment: In the effort of fostering better answers for Stack Overflow, can you explain what you did here?  I had to read it a couple times to even notice the difference, it's kind of subtle (given the state of the code indentation).

Comment: are you talking to me? or the reply above from Eliasdx. I couldnt notice any difference either...

Comment: @Clinteney: The details _matter_ in programming. Look closer.

Comment: my bad for forgetting the curly brackets. Thank you but the problem remained.